# Adjoining an inverse to a local UFD of Krull dimension 2 gives a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a local UFD of Krull dimension 2. Let $a\in R$ be a nonzero, non-unit. I am trying to show that the ring $R[1/a]$ is a principal ideal domain. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78006/prove-that-a-ufd-r-is-a-pid-if-and-only-if-every-nonzero-prime-ideal-in-r-is) it follows that you have to prove that the Krull dimension of $R[1/a]$ is $1$. But the maximal ideal of $R$ is the only ideal of height $2$ and this explodes in $R[1/a]$ (since it contains $a$). The prime ideals of $R$ not containing the element $a$ remain prime in $R[1/a]$ and have height at most $1$. This shows that $\dim R[1/a]=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The set of prime ideals of $R$ consists of

- A single ideal of height 0: $(0)$
- One or more ideals of height 1, all principal
- Exactly one ideal of height 2

The set of prime ideals of $R[1/a]$ consists of the (extensions of) prime ideals of $R$ that do not contain $a$....