# A UFD such that every prime ideal is contained in a principal proper ideal is a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $D$ be a UFD such that every prime ideal is contained in a principal proper ideal. Is then $D$ a PID ?

I can only prove that if every proper ideal of a UFD is contained in a principal proper ideal then it is a PID. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I reflect on it , it seems trivial by the result I already know ... every proper ideal is contained in a prime ideal and by assumption it is contained in a principal proper ideal ... so done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If in a UFD every maximal ideal is principal then it is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262068/if-in-a-ufd-every-maximal-ideal-is-principal-then-it-is-a-pid)