# the condition when a UFD is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that a $UFD$ is a $PID$ if and only if every prime ideal is maximal.

I know a proof but used Zorn's lemma.Is there a proof that doesn't require Zorn's lemma?

Comment: Duplicate: [If in a UFD every maximal ideal is principal then it is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262068/if-in-a-ufd-every-maximal-ideal-is-principal-then-it-is-a-pid) (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262068/if-in-a-ufd-every-maximal-ideal-is-principal-then-it-is-a-pid/3543774#3543774))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a UFD is a PID if and only if every nonzero prime ideal is maximal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78006/prove-that-a-ufd-is-a-pid-if-and-only-if-every-nonzero-prime-ideal-is-maximal)