# Non-unique factorization of an ideal in UFD

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains, dedekind-domain

I know that the factorization of a nontrivial ideal into prime ideals is unique in a Dedekind domain. Not all UFDs are Dedekind domains, so there must be a UFD in which there exists a nonzero ideal with non-unique factorization into prime ideals.

In non-Dedekind UFD $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ideal $(2, x)$ is not principal, but it has unique factorization. So this attempt fails.

Would you please provide an example of a UFD in which the unique factorization of a nonzero ideal into prime ideals is not possible?

Comment: Phrasing a question in this way, in a manner appropriate for a homework assignment, tends not to be welcomed here.  It makes it look as if you're passing on to us a question written by someone other than yourself without including any of your own thoughts about it.

Comment: A please would be nice

Comment: In Z[x], the ideal <2, x> is not principal. I am aware of the result that the factorization of a nontrivial ideal into prime ideals uniquely is possible in a Dedekind domain. Not all UFD are Dedekind domain, so there must be a UFD in which there exist a nonzero ideal with non-unique factorization into prime ideals. But I am unable to find an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew that in a Dedekind domain UFD and PID are equivalent, would you be able to come up with an example yourself?

[Unique factorization domain that is not a Principal ideal domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16754/unique-factorization-domain-that-is-not-a-principal-ideal-domain?rq=1)