# Non-principal ideal in $K[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains

**Context**: Let $K$ be a field. Then $K[x,y]$ is not a PID because $x$ is irreducible but the quotient $K[x,y]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $K[y]$, which is not a field.

So there must be an ideal in there which is not principal.

**Question**: What is an example of such an ideal?

Comment: The obvious guess is $(x)+(y)=(x,y)$.

Comment: True, that one seems to work. If $(x,y)=(g)$ for some $g\in K[x,y]$, then $g$ would divide both $x$ and $y$. Since $g$ divides $x$, $g$ can have no $y^k$ for $k\geq 1$ because that would contribute a power of $y$ to $x$. By the same token, $g$ can have no $x^k$ for $k\geq 1$. Consequently, $g\in K$. But then $(g)=K[x,y]$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: if $R$ is a domain and not a field, take $r\in R$ such that $r\ne0$ and $r$ is not invertible. Then the ideal $(r,x)$ in $R[x]$ is not principal.

Comment: P Vanchinathan's example being the special case $R=K[y], r=y$ ...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, of course, but pointing to a more general solution might reveal helpful.

Comment: Dear @egreg  Of course! My comment was not  a criticism but, on the contrary, wanted to draw the reader's attention to its generality, in that it contains Vanchinathan's answer. In a word, yours is a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $\phi\colon K[x,y]\to K$ defined by $\phi(f) = f(0,0)$ (that is evaluation at $(0,0)$). Check that it is a homomorphism.

So its kernel  consists of polynomials of two variables vanishing at origin; that is they have no constant terms. This is not a principal ideal (in fact all maximal ideals of this ring are non principal).

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Lemma below with $\rm\,C = K[y],\,$ noting $\rm \,0\neq y\,$ [is not a unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242).

**Lemma** $\, $ If $\ \rm \color{#90f}{0\neq c\in domain}\ C\ $ then $\rm \ (c,x) = (f)\ $ in $\rm \,C[x]\,\Rightarrow \,c\,$ is a unit in $\,\rm C.\ $

${\bf Proof}_{\,1}\ $  If $\,(c,x)\!=\!(f)\,$ then $f\mid c\Rightarrow \deg f \!=\! 0$ $\Rightarrow\!\color{#0a0}{f(1)=f(0)},\,$ so eval $\,(c,x)=(f)\,$ at $\,x\!=\!0\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(c)}=\color{#0a0}{(f(0))};\ $ eval at $\,x\!=\!1\Rightarrow (1)= (\color{#0a0}{f(1)})\! = \!(\color{#0a0}{f(0)}) = \color{#c00}{(c)}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}c\mid 1\Rightarrow c\,$ unit.

---

$\bf Proof_{\,2}\ $ Below is an *element-ary* form of above proof (it evaluates *elements* vs. ideals)

$\rm\ \ f\ \in\ (c,x)\ \Rightarrow\ f = c\, g_1 + x\,h_1.\, $ Eval at $\rm\, x = 0\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{f(0)} = cg_1(0) = \color{#0a0}{cd},\,\ d\in  C$

$\rm\  \ c\ \in\ (f)\ \Rightarrow\ c\ =\ f\, g, \ \,\color{#90f}{hence}\,\ \ \deg f\:\! =\:\! 0\:\Rightarrow\:  \color{#c00}f = \color{#0a0}{f(0) = cd}$

$\rm\ \ x\ \in\ (f)\ \Rightarrow\, x\ =\ \color{#c00}f\, h\ =\ \color{#0a0}{cd}\:\!h.\, $ Eval at $\rm\ x\! =\! 1\ \Rightarrow\ 1 = cd\,h(1)\ \Rightarrow\ c\,$ is a unit in $\rm\,C$

---

**Beware** $ $ Our use of $\rm C$ is a $\rm\color{#90f}{domain}$ to infer $\,\deg c=0,\ f\mid c\Rightarrow \deg f = 0\,$ is *crucial* to the proof. This generally fails for non-domains, and so does the Lemma, e.g. in $\,\Bbb Z/6[x]\!:\ (2,x) = (2+3x)\,$ by $\,(2,x)=(2+3x,x)=(2+3x),\,$ by $\,2+3x\mid x,\,$ by $\,(2+3x)(3+2x)=x.\,$ Notice  here we have *positive* degree $ f\mid c,\,$  i.e. $\,2+3x\mid 2\,$ [by $\,-2(2+3x) = 2$].

**Remark** $ $  It is often true that *evaluation* serves to reduce many arithmetical properties of polynomial rings to corresponding properties in their coefficient ring, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/680114/242) and its links for application of such methods to factoring polynomials.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91587/ring-of-polynomials-is-a-principal-ideal-ring-implies-coefficient-ring-is-a-fiel) for general results characterizating when a polynomial ring or semigroup ring R[S] is a PIR (principal ideal ring), e.g. we have

**Theorem**  $\ $ TFAE for a semigroup ring R[S], with unitary ring R, and nonzero torsion-free cancellative monoid S.

1. $\ $  R[S] is a PIR (Principal Ideal Ring)
2. $\ $ R[S] is a general ZPI-ring  (i.e. a Dedekind *ring*, see below)
3. $\ $ R[S] is a multiplication ring  (i.e.  $\rm\ I \supset\ J \Rightarrow\ I\ |\ J\ $  for ideals $\rm\:I,J\:$)
4. $\ $ R is a finite direct sum of fields, and S is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb N$

A  general ZPI-ring  is a ring theoretic analog of a Dedekind domain
i.e. a ring where every ideal is a finite product of prime ideals.
A unitary ring R is a general ZPI-ring $\iff$ R is a finite direct sum
of Dedekind domains and special primary rings (aka SPIR = special PIR)
i.e. local PIRs with nilpotent max ideals. ZPI comes from the German
phrase "Zerlegung in Primideale" = factorization in prime ideals.
The classical results on Dedekind domains were extended to rings
with zero divisors by S. Mori circa 1940, then later by K. Asano
and, more recently, by R. Gilmer. See Gilmer's book "Commutative
Semigroup Rings" sections 18 (and section 13 for the domain case).

Comment: Which is exactly a (hard to read) proof of my hint, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg Please take your incessant rude comments elsewhere.

Comment: Rude? Where? You come by two hours after my answer and give essentially the same. Next thing you do is downvoting my answer. Who's being rude?

Comment: @egreg I had not read your hint. The above proof was composed *long* before this site existed. The reason it is written out in such great detail is that I have seen *many* students struggle with the details, so I think it is worthwhile to teach how to do these things in a very simple way using only evaluation (the above is comprehensible to a high-school student). TIP *polite* critiques are usually much more constructive.

Comment: You should read other answers before giving yours. This one is a clear duplicate and the downvote to mine is completely unjustified (that you gave it is clear from you avoiding to deny you did). My opinion that your proofs are generally hard to read is every day stronger, so what? Is it impolite to criticize your style? I see no impoliteness in my short comment.

Comment: @egreg I have *no interest whatsoever* in your opinions or speculations on these subjective nonmathematical matters. Please have the courtesy to *stop* pinging me on these off-topic matters.

Comment: @BillDubuque Quick question: $g,g_1,h,h_1\in D[x]$, wheres the other variables have degree $0$, thus are in $D$ (or, it looks like you use $C$), correct?

Comment: @User7238  That lone $D$ should be $C$. The hint is meant as intuition for the elementary proof in the Lemma, where $\,c\in C.\,$ I will update it shortly to make the proof even more conceptual (meant to do so long ago).

Comment: @BillDubuque I see!  Thank you so much for taking the time to respond, I really appreciate it!